# Retain SignalR notifications on page refresh or page change

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, oracle, signalr

I needed notifications in my application about any changes made in database, so I use SignalR for that purpose.

My notifications are visible in a dropdown menu like they are in facebook.

When I click any of the notification that are visible as list items in the dropdown menu, I'm redirected to new page on which the data that has been newly added is visible in a grid. And then that particular notification is required to be cleared up from the dropdown menu.

But after redirection, any notifications in my dropdown menu that were left unread also get cleared, the dropdown menu becomes empty. And, due to the page refresh, I am not able to view those notifications again.

I have made this dropdown menu on the home page.

Is there any way I can retain those notifications that were not clicked yet on page change. Or there is any other way to fill that menu list again by hitting the notification hub method so that I get those unread notifications again.

Comment: Notifications should be coming from the DB as well as SignalR.  If you *only* use SignalR then of course you'll lose the info when you change page or refresh.

Comment: Yes notifications are only visible when a new row is added to my database.

Comment: I have used oracledependecy

Comment: If they're in the database then you need to get them when the page is loaded and display them.  Forget about SignalR and definitely forget about using it to display something at page load.

Comment: Is there any way to store that entire dropdown menu and reuse it at page refresh

Comment: Yes - store it in the database (like you already do) and then get it when the page is loaded.  Stop trying to reuse SignalR notifications - that's not what it's for.  Imagine that the notification is sent and your browser is not open.  When you visit the site you need to see the notifications so they have to come from the database, not old SignalR messages.

Comment: yes, thank you @Archer, now I'm doing it with ajax.

Comment: Improve readability.

Comment: If you want to have notification like facebook, then you will need to create a table that stores the notification by user. In this table, you will have a read flag as one of the columns. Once the user clears that notification, then you add to that read column. On your user client code, you will display the notification when the read column is null.